# AutowireViewModel does not work when inside a Prism Module

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am sure I am doing something wrong here, but when I set AutowireViewModel attach property in the view defined in a module, it cannot auto-wire up the view model. I do not see the view model instantiated. My sample project is at github (see below)

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainModule.ToolbarWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop"
         mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Test</Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

https://github.com/rohits79/PrismAutoWire/tree/master/Prism%20App/MainModule

Please ignore the hardcoded path at https://github.com/rohits79/PrismAutoWire/blob/master/Prism%20App/Prism%20App/Bootstrapper.cs#L34

Comment: Is the UserControl used in an ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl?

Comment: No, please look at the source code on the github

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got the namespaces wrong.

```
namespace MainModule
```

[...]

```
public partial class ToolbarWindow
```

The view has to reside in `Whatever.Views` and the view model in `Whatever.ViewModels` if you don't want to change the default resolution scheme.

So move `ToolbarWindow` into `MainModule.Views` and you're good to go.

BTW: `IView` isn't needed anymore with Prism 6

Comment: This did the trick for me. I had my namespaces as Something.View and Something.ViewModel, so AutoWire wasn't working. Once I pluralized them to Views and ViewModels, success!